# Como posso obter o BluetoothManager do dispositivo no Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, bluetooth

Estou aprendendo sobre Bluetooth em Kotlin e estava lendo este documento do Google sobre BluetoothAdapter https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter. Comecei a implementar o código para dispositivos Android com a API 6.0 (superior a JELLY_BEAN_MR1) e tenho alguns problemas para obter o BluetoothManager. Aqui está o código em que estou trabalhando:

```
lateinit var mBluetoothManager:BluetoothManager
fun foo(context:Context){
      this.mBluetoothManager = context.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE)
}
```

O Android Studio mostra que é uma incompatibilidade de tipos (obrigatório: BluetoothManager, Founded: Any!). Então, como posso obter a instância do BluetoothManager, eu fiz algo de errado? Por que preciso ligar dessa forma usando o SystemService e não dessa forma:

```
var mBluetoothManager = BluetoothManager()
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Porque o método [**`getSystemService`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/Context#getsystemservice) é um método feito para funcionar de forma genérica e retornar qualquer tipo de serviço do sistema, não apenas um gerenciador de *bluetooth*. Desta forma, o retorno do método é `Any!` (Kotlin) / `Object` (Java).

Portanto, falta fazer uma conversão para o tipo de destino

```
this.mBluetoothManager = 
    context.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
```

> Por que preciso ligar dessa forma usando o SystemService e não dessa forma `var mBluetoothManager = BluetoothManager()`?

Porque, da segunda forma, você estaria criando uma instância de `BluetoothManager`, mas não é isso que você precisa. Você precisa obter uma instância a partir de `Context`.

Comment: Entáo quando eu mudar de contexto eu preciso chamar o getSystemService novamente?